# How to handle 'throw new DecryptException('The payload is invalid.')' on Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have small Laravel project working on Crypt class. It work fine for both Crypt::encrypt(..) and Crypt::decrypt(..). But I have problem if I directly change on crypted value then try to capture exception. For example, my crypted value is

```
zczc1234j5j3jh38234wsdfsdf214
```

Then I directly add some words as below.

```
zczc1234j5j3jh38234wsdfsdf214_addsometext
```

I try to decrypt and get error as below

```
throw new DecryptException('The payload is invalid.')
```

So, I try to capture exception with render method.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException) {
        dd("error");
        return route('login')->withError('Your DB may be hacked');
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

I do not known why method not fire, Appreciated&thanks for all comment.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, where do you put that render method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should handle this with

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException;

try {
    $decrypted = decrypt($encryptedValue);
} catch (DecryptException $e) {
    //
}
```

check https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/encryption

Comment: Hi Rajat Sharma,Thanks.

Comment: At long last! Simple and concise